# HTTP Toolkit CA is rejected by client while using 'anything' setup mode

Tags: ssl-certificate, ca, http-toolkit

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4kUw.png)

I make sure to export the CA certificate provided and run it, but I received a CA certificate not trusted error. I'm suspecting it's the way I'm downloading the certificate, but I'm open to other help or suggestions.

Comment: It's an issue with the client browser (it does not trust your cert). The setup is a bit different for every browser/OS combination.

Comment: Can you share more detail about the client you're using? The client must trust the certificate exported from HTTP Toolkit, but the steps will be different for every type of client.

Comment: @HEllRZA I’m using the latest chrome browser as my client. I’m also on the latest windows 10. What should I do to setup for that specific combination?

Comment: @TimPerry by client so you mean my browser and operating system?

Comment: Yes, client browser and OS, just as i wrote before.

Comment: https://httptoolkit.tech/docs/reference/intercept-page/ Click on "Fresh Chrome" there.